# Error building / installing Go (golang) packages bound to SDL2 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, go, sdl, pkg-config

On OSX, when building (`go get`) any go package that links to SDL2, I always get the same error. (tried on four different Go packages that use SDL2)

For example with the *tenema/amore packages*:

```
$ go get -u github.com/tanema/amore/...
# pkg-config --cflags sdl2
error <autogenerated>: no library found in $GOPATH: sdl2
error $GOPATH: no library found in $GOPATH: sdl2
error github.com: PKG_CONDIF_GITHUB not exported, skipping github.com lookup
error $PKG_CONFIG_PATH: open sdl2.pc: no such file or directory
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

SDL2 was installed using `brew`, which is the suggested way to install it in any of the Go packages I've tried.

```
brew search sdl2
sdl2 ✔                     sdl2_image ✔               sdl2_net ✔               
sdl2_gfx ✔                 sdl2_mixer ✔               sdl2_ttf ✔
```

The SDL2 libraries are where you expect them to be:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/ | grep sdl
sdl2
sdl2_gfx
sdl2_image
sdl2_mixer
sdl2_net
sdl2_ttf
```

The Go version of `pkg-config` is installed (and the original also).

```
$ which pkg-config
/Users/myself/Go/bin/pkg-config
```

I've Googled for it, but to no avail, searching for `"error $GOPATH: no library found in $GOPATH:"` returns only 1 result, which doesn't seems to apply.

I also have a pretty clean and sane Xcode and Go environment (compilers and all).

I'll continue searching on my side, but if any of you have a clue on how to resolve that error, that would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the "Go version" of pkg-config? That's likely not doing what you expect.

Comment: @JimB : Good point, but I did _"go get"_ it from `github.com/rjeczalik/pkgconfig`, it's compiled with my current go compiler (1.7.1).

Comment: That looks like a very incomplete attempt at a pkg-config replacement in Go. Just use the real "pkg-config"

Comment: @JimB You are so right, I was stupid and thought that the Go implementation was the real one because I was installing a Go module. I now works with pkg-config from _brew_ on osx. Thanks a lot.